# Laravel Optimize Command with `--force` Option Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When I run the `php artisan optimize` command with the `--force` option, my application instance doesn't work at **http://localhost/project/public/invoice/create**.

However, it does work at **http://localhost:8000/invoice/create** when I run `php artisan serve`.

Why isn't **http://localhost/project/public/invoice/create** working? How can I rollback?

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel file structure is set up:

```
public
  |-- css
          | -- app.css
  |-- js
          | -- app.js
          | -- some-other.js
  |-- index.php
```

These files referenced as follows:

http://localhost/css/app.css

http://localhost/js/app.js

http://localhost/index.php OR http://localhost/

The **/public** directory is the base and contains the index.php file, which is the entry point for all requests entering your application and configures autoloading. This directory also houses your assets such as images, JavaScript, and CSS.

Comment: how to undo that

Comment: Undo what? There's nothing to rollback.

Comment: Its totally another problem, composer dump autoload not working in pho 5.4.7 solved it

Comment: Are you attempting to generate optimized autoload files? 'composer dump-autoload -o' ? Sorry, not quite understanding exactly what you are trying to do.